# Outlook calendar replaces plus sign in meeting organizer email address with spaces

Tags: outlook, calendar, office365, ms-office, icalendar

I receive calendar invite to my outlook desktop client from one of the applications I use and the organizer email in the meeting invite was "scheduling-assistant+A6B890782A404B77@XXXXXX.com" (Masking the domain with X). When I tried to accept the meeting invite, I received the following exception

*Delivery has failed to these recipients or groups:
  Scheduling Assistant
  The format of the email address isn't correct. A correct address looks like this: someone@example.com. Please check the recipient's email address and try to resend the message.*

**More information:**
  *scheduling-assistant A6B890782A404B77@XXXXXX.com
  Remote Server returned '550 5.1.3 STOREDRV.Submit; invalid recipient address'*

**ORGANIZER PROPERTY IN ICS FILE**

> ORGANIZER;CN=Calendar
>   Services:mailto:scheduling-assistant+A6B890782A404B77@XXXXXX.com

If we take a look at the email address in the delivery failed mail, plus sign was removed.

Answer (score 0):

I have also recently started facing this issue. I think outlook must have made some changes to how it reads the `.ics` file.

You need to HTTP encode the organizer's email adderss.

I use python (django), and I used `django.utils.http.urlquote` to encode the email address:

```
organizer = vCalAddress(u"mailto:{}".format(urlquote("scheduling-assistant+A6B890782A404B77@XXXXXX.com"))) #<-- This is the only difference. I have encoded the email address.
```

This fixed the problem for me. I have tested this in Outlook and Google calendar.
[Here is my original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57442027/1237117).