# The 'plus' sign in the email address is converted to space in outlook

Tags: outlook, icalendar

The application I am working on sends automatic emails with ICS files for meeting invites. These emails have a reply-to address with a `+` sign in it.

This works fine in google calendar and gmail, but gets replaced by a `space` in outlook. This was working fine in outlook also until about a month ago.

How do I instruct outlook not to interpret it as a ?
Following are some relevant screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a few trial-and-errors, I found out that this happens only when there is an `.ics` file in the email and that outlook was decoding the organizer's email address for some reason. So, `event+yi76iq@domain.com` was converted to `event yi76iq@domain.com`.

So, I encoded the email address while preparing the `.ics` for the calendar event. Here is a snippet of the code - (I am using `django` here and I have used `urlencode` to encode the email address).

```
from django.utils.http import urlquote
.
.
organizer = vCalAddress(u"mailto:{}".format(urlquote(communication_sending_email))) #<-- This is the only difference. I have encoded the email address.
organizer.params['cn'] = vText(organizer_full_name)
event.add('organizer', organizer)
cal = Calendar()
cal.add_component(event)
```

The result in the `.ics` file is `event%2Byi76iq%40domain.com`. I tested this in both **Google calendar** and **Outlook** and it worked.